# setProperty must be overridden by all subclasses of SOAPMessage

Tags: soap, windows-7, jboss, esb

My environment is: Windows7 32, jboss-5.1.0.GA, jdk1.6.0_20. 
When trying to run a SOAP-message I get the following error:
In short:

```
#java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: setProperty must be overridden by all subclasses of SOAPMessage
```

Whole error: http://pastebin.com/zjF6wsF9

I can not figure out how to solve this. I've goggled around and found something about moving some jar-files to lib endorsed (from JBOSS_HOME\lib\endorsed to JAVA_HOME\lib\endorsed) but it still does not work.

For the guy next to me, it all works fine. However he is using Windows XP. We made the same kind of configurations, so it should not be a problem. It feels like the difference in OS changes the outcome. Cant figure out what needs to be made different to get it to work though.

Tips/ideas are much appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the message it looks like you're having a compatibility problem with your java version and the jbossws version.

Did you apply the following described in [release notes](http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/jbossas/tags/JBoss_5_1_0_GA/build/docs/readme.html) under title "from 5.0.0.GA"? You mention something similar in your question but I'm not sure if it's what you're referring.

Comment: Sir, you are a very brilliant man!
Can't belive I did not find this earlier, I've found a lot of similar fixes, but nothing likes this. I guess I'm a bad googler :).THANKS!